# AlaSql Excel (.xls) formatting cell value to be of number

Tags: alasql

I am using AlaSql 0.4.2 to export to excel. Details about the issue is mentioned at : https://github.com/agershun/alasql/issues/967

I would like to know how to set the option while exporting such that the cell format should be number instead of general format.